# Knockout error: dataToRetain is undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having issues with multiple observableArray and adding/remove items with them in one view model.

The scenario is basically a contact management form, so I'm trying to allow them to enter multiple email addresses/telephone numbers etc.

Here is a test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rhv9/

Try adding a few emails and telephone numbers till the error happens.

If it helps, I'm on Firefox 12.

I based my code on this sample on the knockout website:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `var self = this;` in telephone and email definition. Fixed jsfiddle example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rhv9/1/

Comment: D'oh! Been staring at it for too long :(

Answer (score 1):

I changed it so these functions did var self = this..... seems to work ok now

```
var self = this;
            self.Number = ko.observable();
            self.Notes = ko.observable();
            self.ContactType = ko.observable();
        };

        var email = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Email = ko.observable();
            self.Notes = ko.observable();
            self.ContactType = ko.observable();
        };
```